# Android tabbed ActionBar regarding calling a specific class

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I've got an application that uses Android ActionBar with 2 tabs.

On one of the tabs I've got a class that does a SQL INSERT, ("saveRecord") that I'd like to call from a button on Tab1.

This class, saveRecord is located in the file `Tab1.java`, not `MainActivity.java` as shown in the error message below,

```
03-20 10:40:09.448: E/AndroidRuntime(723): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method saveRecord(View) in the activity class net.example.myProgram.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

and called by `tab1.xml`,

```
 <Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Save" 
    android:onClick="saveRecord">
 </Button>
```

How do I get `tab1.xml` to call the method in `Tab1.java` rather than `MainActivity.java`? 
Thanks.

UPDATE:
Below is the code that I ended up inserting into the fragment. I'm trying to keep everything compartmentalized with fragment resources in fragment.java files and minimize language leakage into MainActivity.java.

```
 public class DataEdit extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle       savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dataedit, container, false);     
    Button btnSaveRecord = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
    btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSaveRecordxml:
        saveRecord(v);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "onClick" has to be implemented on the Activity which hosts the layout. You can achieve what you want in the following steps:

1. Implement "public void saveRecord(View view){}" in MainActivity.java.
2. MainActivity.java should have reference to Tab1 object.
3. Create a method on Tab1 to implement record saving logic (SQL insert)
4. MainActivity.java calls the method created from step 3 on Tab1 object when it receives button click event in saveRecord().

Hope it helps.